# Keep nested attribute's values to show validation errors on form submit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, nested-attributes

I have a model `Parent`

```rb
class Parent < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :jobs
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :jobs, allow_destroy: true
end
```

and model `Job`

```rb
class Job < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :parent
  belongs_to :category
  scope :for_category, ->(c) { joins(:category).where(category: { name: c }) }

  validates :destination, presence: true 
end
```

and the form looks like

```
= simple_nested_form_for @account, url: account_path, remote :true
   = f.simple_fields_for :jobs, @jobs do |jobs_form|
     = jobs_form.input :destination, as: :string
```

and the controller responsible looks like

```rb
class AccountsController < BaseController
  before_action :fetch_jobs

  def edit

  end

  def update
    @account.update(account_params)
    unless @account.valid?
      render :edit
    end
  end

  private
  def fetch_jobs
    @account.jobs.for_category(params['category'])
  end  
end
```

When the form is submitted, and the validation fails, I want to show those unsaved objects and the errors. But they are removed from `@account` object.
I have tried doing `@account.assign_attributes` to do `@account.save` later but even `assign_attributes` doesn't assign attribute for nested objects. I'm guessing the `scope` fetches it from database instead of the object's attribute in memory.

How can I keep the nested attribute in the @account object even though the validation failed so that I can show validation errors by highlighting the nested objects in view?